# write z-value from polygon layer to point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, database, st-intersects, virtual-layer, z-value

I have two layers:
1 polygon layer where the depth of an area is written in the database (as DRVAL1) and and where the depth is exported as a Z-value to the geometry.
1 point layer that I use to plan Aids-to-Navigation.
[image: two test opjects.]

In the screenshot to test objects are placed in the point layer. I want to write the depth from the polygonlayer (that is displayed under the pointlayer) that is true for the position of the point, to the poinlayer.

I've tried to make a virtual field in the pointlayer with:

```
 CASE
 (WHEN intersects($geometry,geometry(get_features('layer_id',"DRVAL1", 
 '50')))) = true THEN '50'
 END
```

I've repeated the WHEN->THEN for all the values in the polygonlager.
but I get a reply with (can't convert to double) or (can't find DRVAL1)

what do I need to change or are there better ways to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the RefFunctions plugin as @Joseph suggests, there's no need to use conditional statements. Instead, use the `geomintersects()` function to get the 'DRVAL' value of the polygon that the point intersects, like this:

```
geomintersects( 'polygonlayer', 'DRVAL1')
```

---

Note: Your expression uses a function called `get_features()` (plural). That function doesn't exist, but there's a function `get_feature()` (singular). It "returns the **first** feature of a layer matching a given attribute value." So if your polygon layer has more than one feature with `'DRVAL1' = 50`, `intersects($geometry,geometry(get_feature('layer_id',"DRVAL1", 
 '50')))` will return false if the current point intersects a different polygon than whichever one QGIS decides is the first. This limitation of the built-in geometry functions is exactly why the RefFunctions plugin exists.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the limitation you described in get_feature, neither of the existence of RefFunctions, many thanks. Still getting a NULL reply if i use this method. Will try harder.

Comment: A few suggestions: Make sure you substituted the correct layer and field names into the expression (check your spelling and look for leading or ending whitespace). Double-check that the "polygon layer" is actually polygons, not lines. Try `geomwithin()` instead of `geomintersects()`.

Comment: I tried both but somewhere i’m going wrong. I know the spelling is right cause if it isn’t i get an error. I tried dissolving and then singleparts to multiparts. Both no succes, i just get a read-out (NULL). Is it possible both layers need to have the same CRS?

Comment: yes. always use the same crs for geometry operations (union, intersect, etc).

Comment: problem solved, works flawless, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to install the **refFunctions** plugin as this contains a set of geospatial expressions which can be called from the field calculator. You could then use something like:

```
CASE 
WHEN geomintersects( 'polygonlayer', 'DRVAL1') = '50'
THEN '50'
END
```

where `polygonlayer` is the name of your polygon layer.